# total value of all radiobuttonlist values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, average, radiobuttonlist, selectedvalue

I have 20 `radiobuttonlists` on a page. Each has 4 options with values 1, 2, 3 and 4.

What I need to do is on submitting the form, get the total value of all the `radiobuttonlists` (eg 3+1+2+3+4...) divided by the total number that have actually been filled in (none of them are required fields so anything from 0 to 20 of them could have been filled in) - hence getting an average value.

Is there an easy / elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would embed the RadioButtonLists in a Panel or an other Container-control. Then you can loop its control-collection to get all RadioButtonLists.

Do you want to divide by the number of RBL's or by the number of selected RBL's?

Example that divides by RBL-Count,hence counts non selected as zero, and rounds to next integer:

aspx:

```
   <asp:Panel ID="OptionPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <!-- and so on ... -->
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="BtnCalculate" runat="server" Text="calculate average value" />
    <asp:Label ID="LblResult" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

and in codebehind:

```
    Protected Sub BtnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCalculate.Click
        Dim rblCount As Int32
        Dim total As Int32
        Dim avg As Int32
        For Each ctrl As UI.Control In Me.OptionPanel.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButtonList Then
                rblCount += 1
                Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(ctrl, RadioButtonList)
                If rbl.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
                    Dim value As Int32 = Int32.Parse(rbl.SelectedValue)
                    total += value
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If rblCount <> 0 Then
            avg = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(total / rblCount, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
        End If
        Me.LblResult.Text = "Average: " & avg
    End Sub
```

According to youre new informations that you need to count only the selected RadioButtonLists and ignore f.e. RadioButtonList14 completely, have a look:

```
If rbl.SelectedIndex <> -1 AndAlso rbl.ID <> "RadioButtonList14" Then
   Dim value As Int32 = Int32.Parse(rbl.SelectedValue)
   total += value
   rblCount += 1 'count only the selected RadiobuttonLists'
End If
```

I have moved `rblCount += 1` into the `If rbl.SelectedIndex <> -1`-Statement, besides i've added `rbl.ID <> "RadioButtonList14"` as additional restriction to ignore this RadioButtonList.

Comment: I like this solution... Is it possible to ignore certain columns when getting the average?

Comment: @Tom: Of course, but define "certain" columns! You see how i counted the total-value. It should be easy to customize it accordingly. Btw, it took 10 days to comment my answer? ;-)

Comment: By columns, I meant radiobuttonlists. Sorry. I need to ignore any which have not been filled in, plus radiobuttonlist14 for example.

Comment: @Tom: you need to ignore radiobuttonlist14 completely or you need to count radiobuttonlist14's value as 0 if nothing was selected?

Comment: I need to ignore radiobuttonlist14 completely - and I need to ignore any lists where nothing was selected. So if list3, list6 and list9 were not filled in do not use them when creating the average. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tom: edited my asnwer. RadiobuttonList14 will be ignored completely and all other will only count if selected. Consider to use meaningful ID's.